# How to login user without password in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a main user with username and password. And I have others users with also a username and password.

But now I want that the other users only have to type there username and then they are logged in.

But the problem is that the method:

```
 public virtual IShopAccount GetShopAccount(Guid shopAccountId, bool validOnly);
```

only has a get method.

Because this method comes from:

```
  var salesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccount(Guid.Parse("FED35C7D-7F54-4DD8-9735-EFDFE7E8A738"), true);
```

And ShopAccounts looks like this:

```
  public static ExtendedShopAccountManager ShopAccounts
        {
            get { return (ExtendedShopAccountManager)CommerceFrameworkBase.ShopAccounts; }
        }
```

So is there a way to extend this method with a set method?

Or how to change it that you can change from user to user with only a username?

Thank you

ProfileController has this method:

```
 [HttpPost]

        public virtual ActionResult Login(LoginModel model);
```

And the model looks like this:

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        public LoginModel();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     /// Gets or sets the password. ///
        [AllowHtml]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
        public virtual System.String Password { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to remember the user to login him
        //     automatically on the next visit. ///
        [Display(Name = "Login_RememberMe")]
        public virtual System.Boolean RememberMe { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     /// Gets or sets the username. ///
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_InvalidField")]
        [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
        [StringLength(80, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
        [TrimAttribute(new[] { })]
        public virtual System.String UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: There is no use of password being seen in the code you have shared? How password and these classes are related? You need to share some more details about the use case and flow. Sharing related code would be helpful.

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: Yeah question is bit unclear. I do not understand the business case here as you are allowing users with only user name.

Comment: It is like a cash system. YOu have sales agents who are selling items. And so every sellingagent has a code, like 123. To they type the code in and then they are logged in. But for protection there is one super salesagent who logged in with username and password. And if a ' normal' salesagent logs in he/she overwrites the super salesagent login. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: How are you using the LoginModel to retrieve the account information ? The LoginModel has `password` property decorated with `Required` attribute so it will make sure that user enters the password before submitting the form. Then I think the first thing you need to do is either remove the password property or remove `Required` attribute from on top of it. Why dont' you have a different model for normal sales agent login which does not require password ?

Comment: Yes, oke. But how to make distinction about normal sales agent and just sales agent? Because you can have many Super sales agents and many  normal sales agents

Comment: And also the problem is that I can't modify the model because it is a DLL